# PHP CodeIgniter load view issue, loading full path twice

Tags: php, codeigniter, localhost

I'm new to PHP CodeIgniter and I'm creating my first app, I've created the controller, model and views to add records to my DB and so far so good,

The problem starts when I click 'submit' in my form,

as instead of redirecting to the same form again if there is an issue in the form or redirecting to the success page, it redirects to the same page but with the full path twice,

like this:

form page - localhost/index.php/news/create

expected results:

form data is valid ->localhost/index.php/news/success

form is invalid -> localhost/index.php/news/create (same page)

but instead it does this when I click submit:

localhost/index.php/news/localhost/index.php/news/create

as you can see, it takes the full path again and puts it afterwards the already existing url.

this is my code

routes.php

```
$route['news/create'] = 'news/create';
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['news/create'] = 'news/create';
```

main controller

```
public function view($page = 'home')
    {
            if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
            {
                    // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                    show_404();
            }

            $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
```

controller that has the function create of the form

```
class News extends CI_Controller {
        public function create()
        {
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $data['title'] = 'Create a news item';

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'Text', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
            {
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('news/create');
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');

            }
            else
            {
                $this->news_model->set_news();
                $this->load->view('news/success');
            }
        }
}
```

model:

```
public function set_news()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');

        $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

        $data = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'slug' => $slug,
            'text' => $this->input->post('text')
        );

        return $this->db->insert('news', $data);
    }
```

Form

```
<h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('news/create'); ?>

    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="input" name="title" /><br />

    <label for="text">Text</label>
    <textarea name="text"></textarea><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create news item" />

</form>
```

Comment: Could you post the Form-HTML that's being shown in your browser?

Comment: =======

<html>
        <head>
                <title>CodeIgniter Tutorial</title>
        </head>
        <body>

                <h1>Create a news item</h1><h2>Create a news item</h2>


<form action="localhost/index.php/news/create" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="input" name="title" /><br />

    <label for="text">Text</label>
    <textarea name="text"></textarea><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create news item" />

</form>    <em>&copy; 2015</em>
        </body>
</html>

======

Comment: what's your base_url set to in config.php?

Comment: this is my base url:
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost';

and this is my index page:
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

Comment: Have you tried `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';` ?

Comment: I think you loaded view two times in that controller because I was facing the same issue

Comment: @tobifasc thanks that worked!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @tobifasc for the answer,

The problem was in config.php

I replaced

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost';
```

to this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';
```

and everything is working properly now

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because you have already view loaded and when your validation failed again you loaded your same view so you don't need to view again. Replace your News controller the create method by this code  EX:

```
class News extends CI_Controller {
        public function create()
        {
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $data['title'] = 'Create a news item';

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'Text', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                $this->news_model->set_news();
                $this->load->view('news/success');
            }
        }
}
```